# serial to parallel lcd converter

Tags: serial, lcd

Im looking for some information on a serial to parallel lcd converter.  Im trying to retro fit a 240x64 led lcd with a 8 bit paralell in a machine with serial pixilated data.  I have been searching and found some converters but they are not compatible with this format.  Im willing to do a small run and have they have produced if possible.  Any help or information is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the timing and voltage protocols for both ends?

Comment: Please forgive me if I provide the wrong info.  My knowledge is very limited but The lcd controller on the motherboard is a sanyo lc7981.   The lcd I want to use is a 5.2" 240x64 22 pin arduino display.  As far as voltage the connector on the serial display is 10 pin.  +5v and -0 for contrast.  The 8 bit lcd is +5v and 0v

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented parallel LCD interfaces using a simple [74HC595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf) shift register. Just write a routine to convert your function calls to a serial-out schema and continue using it how you otherwise would have had it been parallel-out.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a small microcontroller.  Using a microcontroller, such as a PIC (as small as a PIC16 would do), or an AVR (one of the 8 bit ATMega series), or other similar small microcontroller, you could write a program to receive your serial data and decode it into the correct parallel instructions for the LCD screen.

Depending on the style of your serial data it may be better or easier to use a slightly more powerful microcontroller (maybe PIC32 or AVR32, for example) - one with more RAM - enough RAM to store a complete framebuffer of the LCD image and update that from the serial data then push the entire screen image out to the LCD screen in one shot.